# Why does the ZF2 autoloader build the path wrongly?

Tags: zend-framework2, autoload, autoloader

I have an application with some modules. One of them is `CourseSearch`. Now I want to add a further one, the `SportsPartnerSearch`. Since these two modules are very similar to each other, I simply "cloned" / copied the `CourseSearch` and replaced all "Course" with "SportsPartner" (in all variations: `$course` to `$sportsPartner`, `course-...phtml` to `sports-partner-...phtml` etc.), in order to edit the logic in the second step. Now I'm getting following errors:

> Warning:
>   require_once(/path/to/project/module/SportsPartnerSearch//src/CourseSearch/View/Helper/CourseSearchForm.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Loader/ClassMapAutoloader.php
>   on line 140
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/path/to/project/module/SportsPartnerSearch//src/CourseSearch/View/Helper/CourseSearchForm.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Loader/ClassMapAutoloader.php
>   on line 140

Why is the path to the file being built in such strange way: `/path/to/project/module/`**`SportsPartnerSearch`**`//src/`**`CourseSearch`**`/View/Helper/CourseSearchForm.php`? Where did I do a mistake?

---

Some additional information.

The class, that cannot be found because the wron path is `CourseSearch\View\Helper\CourseSearchForm` in the CourseSearch module. It can be found, when I deactivate the new module `SportsPartnerSearch`, that contains the class `SportsPartnerSearch\View\Helper\SportsPartnerSearchForm`.

The `CourseSearchForm` view helper is instanciated in the `CourseSearchForm\Module`

```
class Module {
    public function getViewHelperConfig() {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'courseSearchForm' => function($serviceManager) {
                    $helper = new View\Helper\CourseSearchForm(array('render' => true, 'redirect' => false));
                    // ERROR. This code is not executed anymore.
                    $helper->setViewTemplate('course-search/course-search/course-search-form');
                    $courseSearchForm = $serviceManager->getServiceLocator()->get('CourseSearch\Form\CourseSearchForm');
                    $helper->setCourseSearchForm($courseSearchForm);
                    return $helper;
                }
            )
        );
    }
}
```

And called in the layout file:

```
echo $this->courseSearchForm();
```

The `SportsPartnerSearch\View\Helper\SportsPartnerSearchForm` is instanciated in the same way in the `SportsPartnerSearch\Module#getViewHelperConfig()` and is not called yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you generated a classmap? Check the `autoload_classmap.php` file in both the CourseSearch and the SportsPartnerSearch modules. I guess you still have an old classmap lying around. I think the problem is hidden inside the classmap because of the error in the ClassMapAutoloader from Zend, and not the standard autoloader.

You can generate a new classmap with the classmap generator provided in ZF2 (assuming you load it via Composer) with:

```
cd module/SportsPartnerSearch
../../vendor/bin/classmap_generator.php
```

This will generate a new classmap file inside the SportsPartnerSearch module.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! It also works now namespace based without generated classmaps. Yesterday I cleaned my `autoload_classmap.php` files and tried it without them, but the error was still occuring. Now I've generated the classmaps again (it worked) and cleaned the maps again and now it's also working namespace based. So, I think, yesterday I forgot to clean one classmap.